# Spring Security 3.2.0RC2 logout url POST only?

Tags: spring-security

I am experimenting with Spring Security 3.2.0.RC2 using javaconfig and it appears that the logout url is POST only. Is this by design and is there any way to make it logout a user with a GET request?

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/signup", "/about", "/password").permitAll()                  
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll();        
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is intentional and is documented within the [CSRF documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-logout). The reason is to prevent CSRF attacks that forcibly log users out of your application. If you would like to support non-POST requests you can do so with the following Java Configuration:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http
    // ...
    .logout()
       .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"));
}
```

You can also find information about configuring log out on the [Javadoc of the LogoutConfigurer](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.RC2/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/LogoutConfigurer.html#logoutUrl(java.lang.String)) (i.e. the object returned by the `http.logout()` method).

Comment: Thanks, almost embarrassing with the answer so clearly documented.

Comment: No problem...in all fairness to yourself I did update the documentation with the example of how to support non-POST logout after seeing the question (although the rest of it including the javadoc example was there previously)

Comment: How would I do that w/ xml configuration?

Comment: You would use <custom-filter> tag to insert an instance of the LogoutFilter