# How to invalidate remember-me on logout?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

Well, I do not implement `PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices` therefore I cannot use `.logout(request, response, auth)`. But I use `JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl` in order to use `PersistentTokenRepository` for remember-me feature.

LogoutController:

```
@Controller
public class LogoutController {

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/logout"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String logout() {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        if(auth != null) {
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
        }

        return "redirect:/login?logout";
    }
}
```

Security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AppSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/playground").hasAnyRole("ROOT", "MODER", "USER")
            .antMatchers("/users/**").hasAnyRole("ROOT", "MODER")
        .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").loginProcessingUrl("/login").failureHandler(customAuthenticationFailureHandler())
        .and()
            .rememberMe().rememberMeParameter("remember-me").tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository()).userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
        .and()
            .logout().logoutUrl("/logout");
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationFailureHandler customAuthenticationFailureHandler() {
        return new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistentTokenRepository persistentTokenRepository() {
        JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl jdbcTokenRepository = new JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl();
        jdbcTokenRepository.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return jdbcTokenRepository;
    }
```

When I log in with remember-me, I cannot log out then. I guess because of remember-me feature. What should I add to LogoutController to make a proper logout proccess?

**Note:** the thing is, that if I just use POST method on logout, then it perfectly works, but I'd like to use GET method and thus I have to create a logout controller to perform get method.

Comment: Can you share your security config ?

Comment: Don't use a controller. Configure Spring Security to allow to logout with a GET request. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333176/spring-security-3-2-0rc2-logout-url-post-only for how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **To sum it up.**

I've managed to test several ways and here what I have got:

1. As M. Deinum suggested in comments, it's possible not to use a controller and nevertheless have a logout with a GET request. [Here it is.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333176/spring-security-3-2-0rc2-logout-url-post-only)

`.logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))`

2. As Andrew Sasha suggested in the answer section, you can disable csrf as it intentionally prevents using GET request. And now you can use a GET request to log out without even using any controller.

`http.csrf().disable()`

3. If you still wish to use the controller, **none** of the following things will help you

`.deleteCookies("remember-me", "JSESSIONID")`
`.invalidateHttpSession(true)`
`.clearAuthentication(true)` 
`.logoutSuccessUrl("/")`

*(I'm not sure, but I feel like it doesn't work because you perform a GET request and use your controller to control logout)*

4. So then you can do it programmatically

First, you add a name for remember me cookie in Spring security config:

```
rememberMe().rememberMeCookieName("remember-me")
```

And then in logout controller add this:

```
String cookieName = "remember-me";
Cookie cookie = new Cookie(cookieName, null);
cookie.setMaxAge(0);
cookie.setPath(StringUtils.hasLength(request.getContextPath()) ? request.getContextPath() : "/");
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

The only problem here is that you have to delete a record from persistent_logins table manually

*(In order to get a request and a response you just pass them into a method `public void logout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)`*

5. It is possible to use a POST request but use it as a link with the help of JavaScript or even plain HTML and CSS.

The solutions for that you can find on [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915917/make-a-link-use-post-instead-of-get).

### **So what do we have here?**

Summarizing everything above I can say that if you want a controller, you have to programmatically write everything yourself (someone would tell that it's a reinventing of a wheel).

Still, it is possible to use a GET request but without controller which is described in the 1st and 2nd positions of the list.

*(The consequences of using a GET request is written within [CSRF Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-logout) and it does not recommend to use a GET request because of its invulnerability.)*

So the last thing that I decided to be my favorite is to make a POST request look like a GET request (use it as a link) with the help of JS or HTML and CSS. And as you use a POST request you kind of have a CSRF protection.

I hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 2):

Try to disable crsf (`http.csrf().disable()`).

The default implementation in spring's security Logout filter is:

```
        if (http.getConfigurer(CsrfConfigurer.class) != null) {
            this.logoutRequestMatcher = new AntPathRequestMatcher(this.logoutUrl, "POST");
        }
        else {
            this.logoutRequestMatcher = new OrRequestMatcher(
                new AntPathRequestMatcher(this.logoutUrl, "GET"),
                new AntPathRequestMatcher(this.logoutUrl, "POST"),
                new AntPathRequestMatcher(this.logoutUrl, "PUT"),
                new AntPathRequestMatcher(this.logoutUrl, "DELETE")
            );
        }
```

as you can see if your Csrf is enabled (by default it's enabled even if you overwride `protected void configure(HttpSecurity http)`) then only `POST` method will be work, if not all are working.

BTW: Are you sure your request reaching the `LogoutController`, because I thing it's uses standard spring security logout mechanism? (To disable it do `http.logout().disable()`, the same as csrf it's enabled by default)

Comment: Suggesting to make the whole application less secure to get a logout function working with a GET is not really a wise thing to do.

Comment: @M.Deinum I feel like an idea to use a GET to log out is not a good idea at all, is it? Wouldn't it be easier and better just to use a POST request but with the help of JS to make it look like a common link?

Comment: Using a GET has some security risks. But you can do a regular form post you don't really need JS for that.

Comment: @THEWaterfall is right disabling csrf has some [security risk](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)), the `post` is safer. Don't implement your own controller, spring security gives you [all needed features](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-logout) (even by default).